# stuck updating initramfs-tools after following previous questions

Tags: apt, initramfs

I'm having trouble trying to update initramfs tools.
I followed the following instructions from H Dirk Schmitt in a previous post discussing this problem.

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends --purge initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/initramfs-tools/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools
```

The system told me there were unmet dependencies initramfs-tools-core
and suggested running

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

which I did but this hangs when it found

```
initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-79-generic
```

and I have no idea what to do next.

any advice?

thanks
Nigel.

I tried to install initramfs-tools from local archive as per starkus's suggestion but I still end up with the same issue.

```
nigel@user-PC:~$ sudo dpkg --configure --pending
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.11) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-4.13.0-31-generic (4.13.0-31.34~16.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
(/boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib  /dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-31-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
(/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info  /linux-image-4.13.0-31-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-31-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
```

Comment: I cant run     sudo update-initramfs -u -k as i can't install initramfs-tools without it hanging. and i can't reinstall the kernel as i get the dpkg interupted, you must run sudo dpkg --configure -a issue which hangs as well.

Comment: hi starkus i can't install initramfs-tools from archive either. which ever way i try i seem to end up back at this point.

Comment: @starkus sorry i don't know what you mean by staging repo?